# Coordinates not plotting correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to create the figure (attached), but when I do, my points are not plotting correctly.  For example, (0,2), plots (0,-1) (or very close to it).  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I plotted the figure in Overleaf and in TexShop to see if want I was doing wrong, but can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,width=6cm}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        axis lines=middle,
                        y axis line style={opacity=0},ytick=\empty,
                        xmin=0,
                        xmax=10,
                        ymin=-3,
                        ymax=3,
                        ]
                    \end{axis}
                        \draw[very thick,blue] (0,2) -- (2,-2) -- (6,1) -- (9,-.5);
                \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TikZ uses centimetre as default unit. Pgfplots uses it's own coordinate system to fit your graph in the available space. Both systems are normally not the same.

If you'd like to give tikz coordinates in the current pgfplots coordinate system, you can prefix the coordinates with `axis cs:` (this will work for all available `compat` options):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    y axis line style={opacity=0},ytick=\empty,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=3,
  ]
    \draw[very thick,blue] (axis cs:0,2) -- (axis cs:2,-2) -- (axis cs:6,1) -- (axis cs:9,-.5);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With recent `pgfplots` is not needed prefix `axis cs:`. Drawing must be inside `axis` environments (what you do, but OP has it outside it).

Comment: @Zarko Oh, good to know that `axis cs` is no longer necessary. Can you please post an answer?

Comment: I already did :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

- It is not recommended to mix `pgfplots` and pure `tikz` syntax for drawing lines in diagram.
- if for some (unknown) reason need to do this, than drawing by `tikz` commands should be inside `axis` environments. If it is not, that it consider centimeters as default units and not scaled distances inside `axis` environment.
- With recent versions of `pgfplots` (if I remember correctly, after version 1,13) you not need to use `axis cs:` options in defining line coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=6cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ytick=\empty,
    xmin=0,     xmax=10,
    ymin=-3,    ymax=3,
            ]
\draw[thick,blue] (0,2) -- (2,-2) -- (6,1) -- (9,-.5);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result you will get with use only `pgfplots` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=6cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ytick=\empty,
    xmin=0,     xmax=10,
    ymin=-3,    ymax=3,
            ]
\addplot +[thick, no marks] coordinates { (0,2) (2,-2) (6,1) (9,-0.5)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont like `pgfplots`, but this simplest `tikz` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(10.3,0) node[right] () {$x$};
        \draw[very thick,blue] (0,2) -- (2,-2) -- (6,1) -- (9,-.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I was just trying to avoid putting the number line in manually as well.